# How to retain the page state/routes of react app within an iframe

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, iframe, react-router

I have a react app which is loaded in an iframe within an angular app. React app uses react router and the angular app has its own routing mechanisms. But when the page refreshes, the iframe keeps loading the initial route ('/'). How can I retain the state/route of the iframe(react app)? Is there any way to load the last loaded route of the iframe?

One method is to send a postMessage from react app to the parent(with the route information) and save it in the local storage and then load the iframe src every time after appending this route. I'm looking for an alternate solution if it is available.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642488/how-to-use-javascript-variable-in-iframe-src

Comment: We have different routing for the angular app and react app. So we cannot define the route of react app from the parent angular app.