# Pass URL from clipboard to iframe via js?

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

So I'm trying to get a url I have stored in the **clipboard** to render in my iframe via url.

Not sure what to make of this code.

```
<iframe id="showskill" scrolling="yes" height="100%" width ="100%" src=""+ ReturnURL()></iframe>
<script>
function ReturnURL() {    
    var el = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.focus();
    document.execCommand('paste');
    var value = el.value;
    document.body.removeChild(el)
    return value;
}
console.log(getClipboard());
</script>
```

Suggestions welcome.

- Ry3yr

Edit:
This looks like a step in the right direction ?
[How to use javascript variable in iframe src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642488/how-to-use-javascript-variable-in-iframe-src)
Edit2: New code, same fate...

Comment: I think you are not using the promise right

Comment: Are you using come sort of templating language? Your JS and HTML are rather mashed together in a way that is definitely not valid on its own (HTML inside a script tag)

Comment: I'm calling an html-iframe from javascript, because I hoped I could (that way) pass the clipboard content to the iframes "src" field. I got the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8726661/3708093